# $scope in not working outside get function

Tags: angularjs

The Second console is getting undefined but first one is working fine.
Previously it was working, don't know it has stoped working.

```
angular.module('JobPortal').controller('UserActivityController',function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $timeout,$stateParams,$cookies, UserActivity){

    var token = $cookies.get('token');
    var param ={'token': token};
    UserActivity.user_get(param).success(function(data) {
        $scope.user_id = data._id;
        console.log($scope.user_id);
    });

    console.log($scope.user_id);

    $scope.profileCompletion = function(form) {
        //console.log($scope.user_id);

        var param = $scope.profComp;
        param.user_id = $scope.user_id;
        console.log(param);
        UserActivity.save_details(param).success(function(data) {
            //$scope.lastActivityID = data._id;
            window.location.href = "/vendor#/upload-resume";
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Because it being assigned in a promise. Doesn't the second console appear first? Btw what's the question or issue you want to solve?

Comment: I need to get the user_id from here, and assiging it into $scope.user_id. then i have use this in another function but same controller. it is giving error.

Comment: `$scope.user_id` is being assigned asynchronously. You could save the promise and use `success` or `then` as you did to assign it. Could you show us that function where you are using it?

Comment: "then i have use this in another function but same controller" then where is the other function in this controller?

Comment: when $scope.profileCompletion will be invoked ?

Comment: on submit of a form

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because second console is executing first.

```
 angular.module('JobPortal').controller('UserActivityController',function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $timeout,$stateParams,$cookies, UserActivity){



 var token = $cookies.get('token');
    var param ={'token': token};
    UserActivity.user_get(param).success(function(data) {
        $scope.user_id = data._id;
        $scope.consoleUser();
    });

    $scope.consoleUser = function() {
        console.log($scope.user_id);
    }

});
```

it will work

Comment: yah it will work, but it is like somehow we have done, why it is not directly working. ?
Plz Plz help

Comment: I have to use that $scope.user_id in another function which is already linked with one click.

Comment: it is not working because as soon as you use a callback it  becomes async.

Comment: How does using a callback becomes it async? And if I use `$scope.consoleUser()` where the second console was it will still return `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

On your controller save the `promise`. And inside your `$scope.profileCompletion` function use it to ensure when that function is called it will wait for the promise to complete if it hasn't at that time.

```
var promise = UserActivity.user_get(param).success(function(data) {
    $scope.user_id = data._id;
    console.log($scope.user_id);
});

$scope.profileCompletion = function(form) {
    promise.then(function(){
        var param = $scope.profComp;
        param.user_id = $scope.user_id;
        UserActivity.save_details(param).success(function(data) {
            //$scope.lastActivityID = data._id;
            window.location.href = "/vendor#/upload-resume";
        });
    }) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with the below one it will work

```
angular.module('JobPortal').controller('UserActivityController',function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $timeout,$stateParams,$cookies, UserActivity){
     $scope.user_id = "";  //add this line
    var token = $cookies.get('token');
    var param ={'token': token};
    UserActivity.user_get(param).success(function(data) {
        $scope.user_id = data._id;
        console.log($scope.user_id);
    });

    console.log($scope.user_id);

    $scope.profileCompletion = function(form) {
        //console.log($scope.user_id);

        var param = $scope.profComp;
        param.user_id = $scope.user_id;
        console.log(param);
        UserActivity.save_details(param).success(function(data) {
            //$scope.lastActivityID = data._id;
            window.location.href = "/vendor#/upload-resume";
        });
    }

});
```